# Multiple classes with the same generic properties and setup, how can I reduce duplicate code?

Tags: swift, generics, abstract-class, swift-protocols, protocol-extension

There are a lot of questions out there that are similar, but I'm having a hard time finding something that explains exactly what I'm looking for

I have multiple `Services`, which handle a generic `Data` type. They currently all subclass an semi-"abstract" class, `DataService`

This is because all of these `Services` have the same stored properties:

```
class DataService<T: Data> {
  let id: String
  let eventDataProviders: [EventDataProvider]
  private let storedDataProviders: [StoredDataProvider]
```

and their `init` are the same as well:

```
init(id: String, eventDataProviders: [EventDataProvider], storedDataProviders: [StoredDataProvider]) {
    self.id = id
    self.storedDataProviders = storedDataProviders
    self.eventDataProviders = eventDataProviders

    self.setupStoredDataProviders()
    self.setupEventDataProviders()
}
```

the `setup` methods are also the same

---

The difference between these classes is how they handle data, currently defined in an "abstract" function

```
func eventReceivedHandler() -> ((T) -> Void) {
    fatalError("DataService does not have eventReceivedHandler defined")
}
```

Most resources recommend Protocols and Protocol Extensions.
Which I would prefer as well, but I think the two things that make that difficult are:

1. Trying to reduce duplicate code by keeping the stored property declarations in one place, and by sharing an `init`
2. The generic type on the class, it doesn't seem straight-forward to maintain that through a protocol

But the problem with this current solution is

1. The "abstract" class is exposed, when we don't want anybody to actually instantiate an instance
2. The `eventReceivedHandler` isn't compiler-enforced

Is there a correct solution here? I thought this architecture may be common enough, but I've really been struggling finding anything around online, my search queries contain too many overused terms

Comment: Does only eventReceivedHandler() have different implementation in all Services?

Comment: yep that's the only one, every service is otherwise the same

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `protocol` that has `eventReceivedHandler()` method, i.e.

```
protocol EventHandler {
    func eventReceivedHandler() -> ((Data)->())
}
```

Since you're defining `T: Data`, I don't think there is even a need for *generic type* `T` since always `Data` is expected in that place.

Now, you can create your `class DataService` as already did,

```
class DataService {
    let id: String
    let eventDataProviders: [EventDataProvider]
    private let storedDataProviders: [StoredDataProvider]

    init(id: String, eventDataProviders: [EventDataProvider], storedDataProviders: [StoredDataProvider]) {
        //....
    }

    func setupStoredDataProviders()  {
        //.....
    }

    func setupEventDataProviders()  {
        //.....
    }
}
```

Now, the `Service` classes will be created like,

```
class Service1: DataService, EventHandler {
    func eventReceivedHandler() -> ((Data) -> ()) {
        //....
    }
}

class Service2: DataService, EventHandler {
    func eventReceivedHandler() -> ((Data) -> ()) {
        //....
    }
}
```

In case you still have any doubts regarding that, you can ask.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a protocol with an associated type :

```
protocol Service {
    associatedtype T
    var eventDataProviders: [EventDataProvider<T>] { get }
    var storedDataProviders: [StoredDataProvider<T>] { get }
}
```

Coupled with generic providers classes :

```
class EventDataProvider<T> {

}

class StoredDataProvider<T> {

}
```

And a concrete class :

```
class DataService<T>: Service {
    let id: String
    let eventDataProviders: [EventDataProvider<T>]
    let storedDataProviders: [StoredDataProvider<T>]

    init(id: String, eventDataProviders: [EventDataProvider<T>], storedDataProviders: [StoredDataProvider<T>]) {
        self.id = id
        self.storedDataProviders = storedDataProviders
        self.eventDataProviders = eventDataProviders

        self.setupStoredDataProviders()
        self.setupEventDataProviders()
    }

    func setupStoredDataProviders() {

    }

    func setupEventDataProviders() {

    }
}
```

Would allow you to have `DataService` instances handling different types of data eg. :

```
let data = DataService<Data>(id: "1", eventDataProviders: [EventDataProvider<Data>()], storedDataProviders: [StoredDataProvider<Data>()])
let data2 = DataService<Int>(id: "2", eventDataProviders: [EventDataProvider<Int>()], storedDataProviders: [StoredDataProvider<Int>()])
```

And you would also gain more type safety as :

```
let data3 = DataService<Data>(id: "3", eventDataProviders: [EventDataProvider<Data>()], storedDataProviders: [StoredDataProvider<Int>()])
```

would trigger :

> Cannot convert value of type '[EventDataProvider]' to expected
>   argument type '[EventDataProvider<_>]'

Unfortunately, you loose access control as `storedDataProviders` is no longer private.